# a simple copy files based on names into two directory with bash

Tags: linux, bash, copy

I have a directory which contains a lot of files with this pattern:

```
part=2020-05-01
part=2020-05-02
part=2020-05-03
.
.
.
```

Now I want to write a bash script and in the middle of this script, I want to copy all these files in two directory base on a specific date-time.

for example, I want to copy all files before **2020--03-10** to **folder1** and copy the other files into **folder2**.

what is the simplest way to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ ls -1
part=2020-02-03
part=2020-03-02
part=2020-03-15
part=2020-05-01
part=2020-05-02
part=2020-05-03
```

The date part of your file names look like a form of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore can be compared lexicographically (as strings).

Use a [glob](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (rather than trying to parse `ls`), split the file name on the `=` and compare to the cutoff using string comparisons:

```
cut="2020-03-10"
for fn in part=*; do 
    if [[ "${fn#*=}" < "$cut" ]]; then 
          #  ^       split the filename on '='
        echo "$fn => dir 1"
        # instead of echoing -- you would mv "$f" "new_path 1"
    else
        echo "$fn => dir 2"
        # again -- replace with the mv you want
    fi      
done
```

This prints:

```
part=2020-02-03 => dir 1
part=2020-03-02 => dir 1
part=2020-03-15 => dir 2
part=2020-05-01 => dir 2
part=2020-05-02 => dir 2
part=2020-05-03 => dir 2
```

You should be able to take it from there!

Comment: it seems to be ok. just when I replace move instead of echo like you said, it copies all the file into first folder nested.

Comment: You will just need to figure out the `mv` with correct quoting and correct path.